# How to find an agent for a children's picture book? 

Tags: publishing, agent, children

I have written (and self-edited) a book, and need to figure out how to expose it to the "right" agents.  I'm a little overwhelmed (and I'm sure I'm not the first), but I do think it is a unique story that at least deserves a "go" and a few others (that are not friends and family, but friends of friends) have agreed. How can I find an agent?

Comment: Welcome to Writers! I've cleaned up your question a bit, in the interests of clarification, but please feel free to revert my edit if I've changed your meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go to [QueryTracker.net](http://querytracker.net/literary_agents.php).
2. Search for agents representing children's literature.
3. Go to those agents' websites. Confirm that you're submitting a book in the right categories for that agent.
4. Put together a query for the agents that you've selected, then send it out.

Comment: Just one thing: If possible, check with the agents website to see if they represent children's books at all, as some of these websites are out of date. This will also allow you to check if they are accepting submissions at the moment.

Comment: @ShantnuTiwari, exactly right. Step #3 is meant to include this research.

Comment: Of course. Didn't read the answer right :)

Answer (score 0):

There are TONS of resources on the Internet about how to find an agent and appropriate ways to query. You can also try other forums like the Ask An Agent forum on [Absolutely Write](http://absolutewrite.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=58).

Good luck!